# Use function in a controller inside a folder that is defined in subfolder Controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok, guys, this is the case...
I am working in an old porject made it with `CodeIgniter v2` (currently all is in localhost). For new features I created a folder called `v1` inside the `api` folder

***The structure of the project:***

> controllers
>
> > api
> >
> > > v1
> > >
> > > > visit.php
> > > >
> > > > orders.php
>
> controller1.php
>
> controller2.php

**The problem is that I can not access to the `visit.php` controller**

to test purposes I set the `visit` controller in the `api` folder an access it whit this:

```
localhost/projectname/index.php/api/visit/visits
```

> *`visits` is the function in the `visit` controller*

With this way everything works!! but, when I set the visit controller in the `v1` folder I get a 404 page not found error.

```
localhost/projectname/index.php/api/v1/visit/visits
```

***Extra***

Another think that have keep in mind is. This project is using a library to the REST API so, in the `visit` controller are tho functions

```
public function visits_get(){
  // return an arrays of visits
}

public function visits_post(){
  // to add a new visit in a bd
}
```

So, the function will be called depends on the request method

I have been reading and I found that I have to configure the route.php, actually I did it but without success.

Thanks and I hope you understand what I am asking!

***ROUTE.php***

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

This is all that the route.php has in it ._.

Comment: kindly, share your route file

Comment: @UsmanAkram is done :)

Comment: " localhost/projectname/index.php/api/v1/visit/visits_get "
Have you tried it ?

Comment: Yeap, but still not working

Comment: I use more depth than this in Codeigniter 3 project, including the same routing of API/v1/Folder/Controller.php etc - It's possible. I assume you're using https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver and have it extended properly?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, any controllers falling outside the `application/controllers/controller_name.php` naming convention need to be explicitly defined inside the `routes.php` file, otherwise CI will not look inside subfolders. It's not much of a problem, actually, add something like this for your controllers:

```
//You'll need to do this for all of your API controllers, unfortunately
$route['api/v1/(:any)'] = 'api/v1/$1';
//If you have controllers taking arguments, eg. /api/v1/stuff/1
$route['api/v1/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'api/v1/$1/$2';

//Catch-all route for 404's, recommended
$route['api/(:any)'] = 'api/v1/error_api';
```

Have a look at the [routing docs for CodeIgniter 2](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html) for more info.

Comment: Actually, yes, I've read the CI docs. I read in a stackoverflow answer that CI does not allow 3 leves folder. Is this is true?

Comment: Honestly I'm not aware of such a restriction. Our own application uses more than 3 but with a different structure because we use different subsites inside the same application (eg. `application/SUBSITE/controllers/api/controller.php`) and it works (of course the subsite feature required a bit of work).